# why my keyboard doesn't work in some programs?

Tags: keyboard, 17.10

Some weeks ago I get the "artful aardvark" version of ubuntu, I love it! But last week the keyboard suddenly stop working, open the terminal and every key works perfectly but when I tried to type in other program (Firefox, text, file search, etc...) none of the keys worked, y plug a wireless keyboard&mouse combo. But there were no change, suddenly starts and stops working. Now the problem shows once in a time, I tried rebooting, shutting down and logging out when it comes but nothing happens. What I can do to aolve it? (Excuse me if this is a simple issue, I'm a newbie in ubuntu